# For every pair of the following formulas, decide whether one follows from the other, or the other way round.

Tags: logic

Could someone please please explain this to me?

I have the following formulas:

(A ∧ B) → C

(A → C) ∧ (B → C)

(A → C) ∨ (B → C)

for the second one, I got (NOT A AND NOT B) OR C)

I don't know if this is correct and I don't really understand the question. Would appreciate it if someone explained it to me.

Comment: You have to prove (or disprove) e.g. : $(A ∧ B) → C \vdash (A → C) ∧ (B → C)$ or $(A → C) ∧ (B → C) \vdash (A ∧ B) → C $. You can use *Natural Deduction* ?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm so lost with this subject. Can you either elaborate so that I can understand or refer me to a link that explains it? I really don't get the whole mathematical logic and I'm trying to understand it but don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use *Natural Deduction*.

For the first "couple" :

1) $(A → C) ∧ (B → C)$ --- assumed

2) $A \land B$ --- assumed [a]

3) $A \rightarrow C$ from 1) by $\land$E

4) $A$ --- from 2) by $\land$E

5) $C$ --- from 3) and 4) by $\rightarrow$E

6) $(A \land B) \rightarrow C$ --- from 2) and 5) by $\rightarrow$I, discharging assumption [a]

Thus, we have proved :

> $(A → C) ∧ (B → C) \vdash (A \land B) \rightarrow C$

that means that the first formula follows from the second one.

---

To show that the other "direction" does not hold, i.e. that :

> $(A \land B) \rightarrow C \nvdash (A → C) ∧ (B → C)$

we have to find a counter-example, i.e. a *valuation* $v$ such that :

> $v((A \land B) \rightarrow C)=$**t** and $v((A → C) ∧ (B → C))=$**f**.

To do this, it is enough to set :

> $v(A)=$**t**, $v(B)=v(C)=$**f**.

In this way, we have that :

> $v(((A \land B) \rightarrow C))=$**t**

and, by truth table for $\rightarrow$ :

> $v((A → C))=$**f** and $v((B → C))=$**t**, and thus : $v((A → C) \land (B → C))=$**f**.

Having found a *valuation* $v$ such that the premise is *true* and the conclusion is *false*, we can conclude that :

> > $(A → C) ∧ (B → C)$ does not follow from $(A \land B) \rightarrow C$

---

---

For the "couple" : second and third formula, the work is easy.

For formulae $\alpha, \beta$ whatever, we can write the following "schematic" derivation :

1) $\alpha \land \beta$ --- assumed

2) $\alpha$ --- from 1) by $\land$E

3) $\alpha \lor \beta$ --- from 2) by $\lor$I.

Thus, we can apply it with ; $\alpha := (A → C)$ and $\beta := (B → C)$ to conclude with :

> $(A → C) ∧ (B → C) \vdash (A → C) \lor (B → C)$.

---

In order to show that :

> $(A → C) \lor (B → C) \vdash (A → C) \land (B → C)$

it is enough to use the above counter-example.

With it, we have that : $v((A → C))=$**f** and $v((B → C))=$**t**.

Thus :

> $v((A → C) \lor (B → C))=$**t**, while $v((A → C) \land (B → C))=$**f**.